# How to fix error : starting the service porviding the vpn connection failed

Tags: kubuntu, vpn, pptp

I'am using Kubuntu .I want to create pptp VPN connection based on the instruction that was given to me from network manager. But the given error was appeared each time.

‌Below are the screenshots from vpn setting and the error.

[image: pptp vpn error message]

[image: pptp vpn settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred when define gateway with a Domain name value ,

incorrect   : gateway = vpn.example.local

correct     : gateway = 172.23.42.123